# How can this feature ranking problem be implemented with Support Vector Classification?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, data-analysis, feature-selection

If I want the classifier to be SVM (using scikit-learn), how can I modify the 'clf' variable such that the svm classifier used for feature ranking results to high accuracy? What parameters/arguments do I need to add ? Which kernel type of SVC ('linear' or 'rbf' or 'sigmoid' or others) would you suggest for best accuracy?
The codes are referred form the following github link:
https://github.com/CynthiaKoopman/Network-Intrusion-Detection/blob/master/RandomForest_IDS.ipynb

I have 10 features which are ranked (with RecursiveFeatureElimination of scikit learn) from 1 to 10 which are from DoS attacks of the NSL-KDD dataset using RandomForestClassifier with 99% accuracy (using RFC as prediction model).

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Create a decision tree classifier. clf is the 'variable for classifier'

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = 2)

# If classifier used is svm
#clf = SVC(kernel = "linear")
#rank all features, i.e continue the elimination until the last one

rfe = RFE(clf, n_features_to_select=1)
rfe.fit(X_newDoS, Y_DoS)
print ("DoS Features sorted by their rank:")
#print (sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), rfe.ranking_), newcolname_DoS)))
sorted_newcolname_DoS = sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), rfe.ranking_), newcolname_DoS))
sorted_newcolname_DoS
```

I expect more or less 99% similarity between the ranked features of the two classifiers, which I didnt observe.